# Shopify Toggle Cart Button location

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I'm currently using the [Shopify Buy Button](https://www.shopify.com/buy-button).

For the most part, I just copy and pasted the embed code and didn't change much. If you scroll all the way down to `"toggle":{`, you'll notice I made it so **iframe** and **sticky** is set to `false`.

---

## The Issue

When a product is added to a cart, a button that toggle's the shopping cart appears in the body. `.shopify-buy-frame.shopify-buy-frame--toggle`

It normally appears as a fixed `div` on the middle right hand corner of the screen but since my **sticky** option is set to false, it is placed at the bottom of the `body`.

I'd like to be able to assign a parent container that this toggle button ends up in. Ideally, I want to put it in my header somewhere and not have it be generated at the bottom of the body of my page.

**For example:**

```
<body>

    <header>
        <div id="cart-toggle">
            <!-- THIS IS WHERE I WANT IT TO APPEAR -->
        </div>
    <header>

<!-- THIS IS WHERE IT APPEARS -->
</body>
```

**Bonus Points** if I can figure out how to generate a second toggle button for my mobile navigation area.

I've searched the [default compenents](https://github.com/Shopify/buy-button-js/blob/master/src/defaults/components.js) and the [developer section](https://github.com/Shopify/buy-button-js/blob/master/docs/customization/index.md) for the toggle options and can't seem to figure it out.

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

---

**My Embed Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
(function () {
  var scriptURL = 'https://sdks.shopifycdn.com/buy-button/latest/buy-button-storefront.min.js';
  if (window.ShopifyBuy){if(window.ShopifyBuy.UI){ShopifyBuyInit();}else{loadScript();}}else{loadScript();}f
  function loadScript() {var script = document.createElement('script');script.async = true;script.src = scriptURL;(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(script);script.onload = ShopifyBuyInit;}
  function ShopifyBuyInit() {
    var client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({domain: 'domain.myshopify.com',apiKey: 'apikey',appId: '0'});
    ShopifyBuy.UI.onReady(client).then(function(ui){ui.createComponent('product',{moneyFormat:'%24%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D',
        
  options:{
    "product":{
      "variantId":"all",
      "width":"240px",
      "contents":{
        "img":false,
        "imgWithCarousel":false,
        "title":false,
        "variantTitle":false,
        "price":false,
        "description":false,
        "buttonWithQuantity":false,
        "quantity":false
      },
      "text":{
        "button":"ADD TO BAG"
      },
      "styles":{
        "product":{
          "text-align":"left",
          "@media(min-width:601px)":{
            "max-width":"100%",
            "margin-left":"0",
            "margin-bottom":"50px"
          }
        },
        "button":{
          "background-color":"#393a39",
          "font-family":"Lato,sans-serif",
          "font-size":"13px",
          "padding-top":"14.5px",
          "padding-bottom":"14.5px",
          "padding-left":"35px",
          "padding-right":"35px",
          ":hover":{
            "background-color":"#333433"
          },
          "border-radius":"0px",
          ":focus":{
            "background-color":"#333433"
          },
          "font-weight":"normal"
        },
        "title":{
          "font-size":"26px"
        },
        "price":{
          "font-size":"18px"
        },
        "quantityInput":{
          "font-size":"13px",
          "padding-top":"14.5px",
          "padding-bottom":"14.5px"
        },
        "compareAt":{
          "font-size":"15px"
        }
      },
      "googleFonts":[
        "Lato"
      ]
    },
    "cart":{

      "contents":{
        "button":true
      },
      "text":{
        "title":"Bag"
      },
      "styles":{
        "button":{
          "background-color":"#393a39",
          "font-family":"Lato,sans-serif",
          "font-size":"13px",
          "padding-top":"14.5px",
          "padding-bottom":"14.5px",
          ":hover":{
            "background-color":"#333433"
          },
          "border-radius":"0px",
          ":focus":{
            "background-color":"#333433"
          },
          "font-weight":"normal"
        },
        "footer":{
          "background-color":"#ffffff"
        }
      },
      "googleFonts":[
        "Lato"
      ]
    },
    "modalProduct":{
      "contents":{
        "img":false,
        "imgWithCarousel":true,
        "variantTitle":false,
        "buttonWithQuantity":true,
        "button":false,
        "quantity":false
      },
      "styles":{
        "product":{
          "@media(min-width:601px)":{
            "max-width":"100%",
            "margin-left":"0px",
            "margin-bottom":"0px"
          }
        },
        "button":{
          "background-color":"#393a39",
          "font-family":"Lato,sans-serif",
          "font-size":"13px",
          "padding-top":"14.5px",
          "padding-bottom":"14.5px",
          "padding-left":"35px",
          "padding-right":"35px",
          ":hover":{
            "background-color":"#333433"
          },
          "border-radius":"0px",
          ":focus":{
            "background-color":"#333433"
          },
          "font-weight":"normal"
        },
        "quantityInput":{
          "font-size":"13px",
          "padding-top":"14.5px",
          "padding-bottom":"14.5px"
        }
      },
      "googleFonts":[
        "Lato"
      ]
    },
    "toggle": {
      "iframe":false,
      "sticky":false,
      "contents":{
        "icon":true,
        "title":false
      },
      "styles":{
        "toggle":{
          "font-family":"Lato,sans-serif",
          "background-color":"#393a39",
          ":hover":{
            "background-color":"#333433"
          },
          ":focus":{
            "background-color":"#333433"
          },
          "font-weight":"normal"
        },
        "count":{
          "font-size":"13px"
        }
      },
      "googleFonts":[
        "Lato"
      ]
    },
    "productSet":{
      "styles":{
        "products":{
          "@media(min-width:601px)":{
            "margin-left":"-20px"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
);});}
})();
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: For starters.. it is mentioned that `iframe:false` removes all the styles.. Secondly, if you are either way having it outside the iframe, why not have a new element on the page that creates a proxy click to this cart element and then hide this cart element?

Comment: @HymnZ I am aware it removes styles. What does style have to do with **ANYTHING**? Please only contribute info related to my question.

Comment: Agreed.. but the second part of the comment looks like a solution for me..

Comment: @HymnZ Please look at my example in the question because I don't see how your comment could contribute to a solution. If I'm missing something I'd very much appreciate an elaboration

Comment: If iframe is set to false, then the toggle button actually gets added to html as an element.. All you have to do is to hide it using css, create an element "x" inside "cart-toggle" .. Now when this element "x" is clicked, make a function generate a click on the toggle button..

Comment: @HymnZ I think you're mistaken between Shopify templates and the Shopify buy button. I am not using the Shopify template system

Comment: my apologizes. you are right.. I was wrong..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`events`](https://github.com/Shopify/buy-button-js/blob/master/docs/customization/index.md#events) option inside `toggle` config to define events you need. Use `afterInit` event to move toggle node in another place after initialization:

```
toggle: {
    events: {
        afterInit: function (component) {
            document.getElementById('cart-toggle').appendChild(component.node);
        },
    }
}
```

I assume that you can`t create two `toggle` components within a single Shopify embed. But you may operate on existing one using media queries in JS (i.e. [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/)), so when your media query matches/unmatches, you move toggle button wherever you like in the DOM (i.e. inside mobile navigation area)

Comment: You. are. the. man! This worked perfectly. Thank you Andrey. Excellent answer I shall look into inquirejs also. I have never heard of that.

Answer (score 1):

Read this on GitHub: [insert toggle in the dom #569](https://github.com/Shopify/buy-button-js/issues/569#issuecomment-447076405)

I needed to do this very same thing. Verified, it worked for me.
You can place a DIV anywhere and use your own CSS to style it.
Yes, remember to set iframe and sticky to false.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly what @radioSPARKS posted works, still in 2021.
Below a cleaner code in full and more details:

HTML:

```
<div id="shopify-toggle"></div>
<div id="shopify-product-component"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
ShopifyBuy.UI.onReady(client).then(function (ui) {
  ui.createComponent('product', {
    ...
    node: document.getElementById('shopify-product-component'),
    toggles: [{node: document.getElementById('shopify-toggle')}], // <== This is it: it replaces this element with the toggle
    options: {
      ...
      toggle: {
        iframe: false,
        sticky: false,
        ...
       }
       ...
     }
  });
});
```